# Dynamic Navigation in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I just started using Backbone.js on a somewhat complex application. In it, I have a login page which has no navigation at all, and an admin and user section, each with its navigation bar. My question is, what is a good way of representing a dynamic navigation bar through backbone.js. I've thought about about creating three different parent views for the login, admin, and user sections. In each view, I can instantiate (or not) the appropriate navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with the parent view idea.  What I would do is set up a main container and use a router to fill in the appropriate "page" view. eg. admin, user.  In those parent views you will have two more views.  One for your nav bar and one for the content.  In the nav bar view you can assign your events and for the various navigation buttons.  Make sure you properly remove views and undelegate events a good example is:

[Zombie View Management.  Undelegating Events](http://lostechies.%C2%ADcom/%C2%ADderickbailey/%C2%AD2011/%C2%AD09/%C2%AD15/%C2%ADzombies-%C2%ADrun-%C2%ADmanaging-%C2%ADpage-%C2%ADtransitions-%C2%ADin-%C2%ADbackbone-%C2%ADapps/%C2%AD)

index.html

```
<div id="main-container">
</div>
```

router.js

```
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({   
routes :{
    "" : "showLogin",
    "user" : "showUser",
},

initialize : function(app){
    this.RM = app.RegionManager;
},

showUser : function(){
    this.RM.show(new app.UserView());
},

showLogin : function(id){
    this.RM.show(new app.LoginView());
}
});
```

region-manager.js

```
var app = app || {};

app.RegionManager = {

el : "#main-container",

show : function(view){
    if(this.current)
        this.current.close();
    this.current = view;
    this.current.render();
    $(this.el).html(this.current.el);
}
};
```

user-view.js

```
app.UserPageView = Backbone.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.children.nav = new app.UserNavBar();
        this.children.content = new app.UserContent();
    },

    render : funciton(){
        this.$el.html(this.children.nav.render().el);
        this.$el.html(this.children.content.render().el);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code was a tremendous help. Also, thanks for the zombie view management link. I just know I would've been scratching my head over that one for a while if not for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let your views declare their header necessities and have your view manager consume them.  I like to define a header property with text and a buttons array - each having an event reference and various things like an enabled() delegate.  My view manager, when loading and displaying this view, will read the property and turn it in to a model that the header binds to.  If no header property exists on the view, no header will be created for it.